# Failed to create shared library with wx and STL, "multiple definition" error?

Tags: stl, wxwidgets

I tried to build a shared library using wx and STL, and failed in an error of "multiple definition of". Please refer to:

- https://code.google.com/p/gppanel/issues/detail?id=7

The declaration of *wxPointListNode* is not found in the sources. The suspicious lines are like these:

```
include/mathplot.h:85:WX_DECLARE_LIST(wxPoint, PointList);
include/mathplot.h:87:WX_DEFINE_LIST(PointList);
include/gpLineLayer.h:16:typedef std::deque<mpPointLayer*> mpPointList_t;
```

What the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All wxWidgets methods with `DEFINE` in their name expand into a definition of something and a definition can only be used once in a module, so it typically can't appear in a header file (unless you can guarantee that it's included by only a single source file). So just don't put it there.

Moreover, if this is your code, you should avoid using the legacy `WX_DECLARE_LIST` macro at all and just use `std::list<>` or `std::vector<>` instead. Or, if you really want to use only wx (which can only be important if you are targeting some embedded platform without good STL implementation), then use `wxVector<>`.

Comment: I moved the DEFINE line from header to the source, the problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Without the actual code this is just a guess, but I suspect that

```
include/mathplot.h:87:WX_DEFINE_LIST(PointList);
```

generates the full definition of PointList, including a non-templated method wxPointListNode::DeleteData.  mathplot.h is included by all of the .cpp files (gpPanel.cpp, gpSeries.cpp, and baseData.cpp).  Each cpp file is compiled into a .o file, so each has its own definition of DeleteData, and when you try to link the .o files together into lib/libgpPanel.so the linker issues the errors you're reporting.

The definition of the method needs to be in its own cpp file that's compiled and linked in.